# Select statement which compares first 7 chars in a string with other 7 chars in other table

Tags: sql

Can I make a SQL statement which takes the first 7 chars in a string in first  table and compares it with the first 7 chars in second table and send back the rows in the second table which have a match?!

Found `SELECT SUBSTR(OrderNo, 1, 7) As NewColumnName from shipment`
for selecting first 7 characters in a string, hope that helps...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a row from table2 if there `EXISTS` a row in table1 with same first 7 characters:

```
select * from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1
              where substr(t1.column,1,7) = substr(t2.column,1,7))
```

Alternatively, do a `JOIN`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
    join table1 t1 on substr(t1.column,1,7) = substr(t2.column,1,7)
```

Perhaps you need to do `select distinct` to remove duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 shipment1
 inner join
 shipment2
 ON SUBSTR(shipment1.OrderNo, 1, 7) = SUBSTR(shipment2.OrderNo, 1, 7)
```